# FBSDK 4 iOS catch user logout

Tags: objective-c, fbsdk

I'm writing this app, that allows a user to login to my service either by registering first to my service, or use their Facebook, Instagram, etc login.
Now, if for some reason, a user has logged in to my app with FB, but decides to click the FB 'Logout' button, I want to offer the opportunity to login alternatively. For that I need to catch the Facebook Logout action.
So, the question is: how to trigger my "-(void)loginAlternatively" method? Where can I find a hook for that?

I tried to add

```
if (![FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        NSLog(@"Logged out of facebook");
    }
```

to my AppDelegate's

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                  openURL:url
                                                        sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                               annotation:annotation
```

since that is where I handle the post-login FB stuff. However, that doesn't seem to be the place.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a matter of reading the documentation...
So:

- Make the viewController a **FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate**
- Add the *- (void)loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton* method to your .m file
- Connect the button's delegate to the viewcontroller in the storyboard. (or declare *myFBButton.delegate= self*.)

Hope this helps others